# Evaluating integral convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have an the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{6} xe^{\frac{x}{2}}\; dx$$

I know that this integral is convergent but I can not find how to evaluate its' convergence other than finding the limit of the function as it goes to negative infinity. Some guidance on this question would be super helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tell me if I got the limits of integration correct.

Comment: the 6 should be on top and the negative infinity on bottom, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You use the definition and the integration by parts.
$$\begin{gathered}
  \int\limits_{ - \infty }^6 {x{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}dx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \int\limits_t^6 {x{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}dx}  = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \int\limits_t^6 {xd\left( {{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}} \right)}  = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \left( {\left. {x{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}} \right|_{x = t}^{x = 6} - \int\limits_t^6 {{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}dx} } \right) \hfill \\
   = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \left( {6{e^3} - t{e^{\frac{t}
{2}}} - 2\left. {{e^{\frac{x}
{2}}}} \right|_t^6} \right) = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  - \infty } \left( {6{e^3} - t{e^{\frac{t}
{2}}} - 2{e^3} + 2{e^{\frac{t}
{2}}}} \right) = 8{e^3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following integral: $$ \int_b^6 x e^{x/2} dx $$

The primitive for the integrand is known, and equals $ 2(x - 2)e^{x/2} $. Therefore:
$$ \int_b^6 x e^{x/2} dx = \left[ 2(x - 2)e^{x/2} \right]_b^6 = 8e^3 - 2(b - 2) e^{b/2}$$

Now we try to evaluate the convergente of the improper integral:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^6 x e^{x/2} dx = \lim_{b \to -\infty}\int_b^6 x e^{x/2} dx = \lim_{b \to -\infty} 8e^3 - 2(b - 2) e^{b/2} = \lim_{b \to \infty} 8e^3 + \dfrac{2(b - 2)}{e^{b/2}}$$

A simple L'Hôpital on the limit will show that $ \int_{-\infty}^6 x e^{x/2} dx = 8e^3$.